# NaN showing even with number (angularjs)

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, nan

In the controller:

```
$scope.startCount = 0;  

    $scope.vs = function (number) {  
        $scope.startCount = number; 
    } 

    $scope.startTimeout = function () {  
        $scope.startCount = $scope.startCount + 1;  
        mytimeout = $timeout($scope.startTimeout, 1000);  
    }  
    $scope.startTimeout();  

    $scope.stopTimeout = function () {  
        $timeout.cancel(mytimeout);  
        alert("Timer Stopped");  
    } 

$scope.meals = [
    { title: 'Abs', url:"#/app/mworkouts",id: 100, img: "img/female.jpg", vid:"vid/1.mp4",},
    { title: 'Arms', url:"#/app/browse",id: 2 , img: "img/male.jpg", vid:"vid/2.mp4"},
    { title: 'Biceps', url:"#/app/search",id: 3, img: "img/Spotify_2.jpg", vid:"vid/1.mp4" },
    { title: 'Legs', url:"#/app/search",id: 4, img: "img/Spotify_4.jpg", vid:"vid/2.mp4" },
    { title: 'Core', url:"#/app/mworkouts",id: 5, img: "img/female.jpg", vid:"vid/1.mp4" },
    { title: 'Back', url:"#/app/mworkouts",id: 6, img: "img/male.jpg", vid:"vid/2.mp4" }
  ];
```

In the html:

```
<div ng-repeat="m in meals">
<button ng-click='vs({{m.id}})'>Setter</button>
</div>
```

So how it is supposed to work is pass in a number from the array and then count up using $timeout. It works perfectly fine if I enter in a number manually but I want the number to come from the array. Also, {{m.id}} is definelty a number because I have tested it {{m.id-60}} and it works. I am have no idea what is wrong.

Sorry about the weird names...it's just an example :)

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/P05ieKq0fkqeLFilG5CD?p=preview checkout your working example. I just edited .

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of the {{}}

```
    ng-click='vs(m.id)'
```

Comment: When answering questions it is best to explain in more detail so that it can be more easily understood by other users of the site

Answer (score 0):

It's seems to work for me here! I added couple of log for you to make sure

```
<div ng-repeat="m in meals">
     <button ng-click='vs(m.id)'>Setter</button>
 </div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:rfqcl9AHEoJZEEJxyNn2?p=preview

Comment: ok...then I must be doing something wrong...I will look into and get back to you guys...Thanks :)